# in Express Checkout Transaction in paypal have some error

Tags: php, paypal

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted/
i try to create transaction using above.but found some error look this
  `TIMESTAMP=2014%2d08%2d26T08%3a19%3a22Z` 
  `&CORRELATIONID=15b6333b464b8` 
`&ACK=Failure`
`&VERSION=0%2e000000`
`&BUILD=12513933`
`&L_ERRORCODE0=10006`
`&L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Version%20error`
`&L_LONGMESSAGE0=Version%20is%20not%20supported`
`&L_SEVERITYCODE0=Error`
please help me to solve this

Comment: At a wild guess I'd say that "Version is not supported".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you are passing the version as "XX.0" . In the documentation it states to pass the version = XX.0 but You need to replace the "XX" with a valid numeric value . You can pass the version as 109.0 or above . For more information  regarding the version refer this [link](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/release-notes/)